# Combining and sorting two collections of data from SharePoint using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

I am new to writing javascript, I want to print out the items in a list as well as subsites in alphabetical order. How can I print this combined output in alphabetical order ? Current output is displaying list items in ABC order then subsites in ABC order.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    GetItems();
});

function GetItems() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "GatheredSites",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            if (Status == 'success') {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                    $("#divItems").append("<li>" + name + "</li>");
                });
                Subsites();
            } else {
                jQuery("#displayItems").append("<div>Empty</div>");
            }

        }
    });

}

function Subsites() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetWebCollection",
        webURL: "*url*",
        async: true,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Webs > Web").each(function() {
                var $node = $(this);
                var liHtml = "<li> <a href='" + $node.attr("Url") + "' >" + $node.attr("Title") + "</a> </li>";
                $("#displayItems").append(liHtml);
            });

        }
    });
}
```

```html
    < div id = "displayItems" >
    < /div>
```

Comment: umm,  i'm not sure what's wrong here?   you said you want them to print out in Alphabetical order,  and then you said they are printing in Alphabetical order...  can you maybe give a snapshot of what it is printing and how you would prefer it to print?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save all the list and subsite names into the same array, then sort the array (using `Array.sort()`) before looping through it to print the results.

```
function GetItems() {
    var names = [];
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "GatheredSites",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            if (Status == 'success') {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                    var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                    names.push(name);
                });
                $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetWebCollection",
                    webURL: "*url*",
                    async: true,
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).find("Webs > Web").each(function () {
                            var $node = $(this);
                            names.push($node.attr("Title"));
                        });
                        names.sort();
                        var output = $("#divItems");
                        for (var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
                            output.append("<li>" + names[i] + "</li>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                jQuery("#displayItems").append("<div>Empty</div>");
            }    
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was trying to do. I was using the array at first it wasnt working. I was calling the sort wrong. Thank you!